# Changing the maximise, minimise and close window buttons on Xubunu?

Tags: windows

I remember on an earlier version of Xubuntu, that there was the ability to change the minimise, maximise and close icons in the title bars of windows to nice 3d coloured ones. I can't seem to do that now. How can I do it, please?